# Actualizar dos tablas a la vez sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas y quiero actualizar la segunda tabla usando un compo relacionado entre las dos tablas.

el campo relacionado entre las tablas se llama **Numero**.
Este query me actualiza un campo llamado **Activo** en *tabla1* y quiero que al actualizar un row tambien me actualize en la *tabla2*

```
 Update Tabla1 
 set ACTIVO = 0
 where ACTIVO = 1
 AND CONVERT(DATE, FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
 and DATEDIFF(Second, GETDATE(),FCH_FIN) < 3;
 go
```

Al update de la *tabla1* quiero agregarle al mismo tiempo el update de la tabla2, el campo que quiero actualizar se llama **Ausente** y como dije arriba la relacion es el campo **Numero** entre ambas.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo con datos de muestra de como deseas que cambien los valores? Verifica que sea un antes y un después y esté en text y no en imagen.

Comment: Deberias usar algun procedimento de almacenado que dispares al momento luego de actulizar la Tabla1. Esto te puedo recomendar con lo que mencionas y por el codigo que agregaste. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, lo que pude serte muy útil es la clausula [`OUTPUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) vigente desde la versión 2005. La idea conceptual es "registrar" en una tabla temporal, las filas que hemos usado en el primer `UPDATE` para luego poder determinar las filas que actualizaremos en la segunda tabla. La idea sería algo así:

```
DECLARE @FilasActualizadas TABLE (numero INT)

UPDATE  Tabla1 
    SET ACTIVO = 0
    OUTPUT inserted.numero INTO @FilasActualizadas
    WHERE   ACTIVO = 1
        AND CONVERT(DATE, FCH_FIN) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
        and DATEDIFF(Second, GETDATE(),FCH_FIN) < 3;

UPDATE  Tabla2
    SET Ausente  = 1
    FROM Tabla2 T2
    INNER JOIN @FilasActualizadas T1
        ON T1.numero = T2.numero
```

La "magia" la hace `OUTPUT inserted.numero INTO @FilasActualizadas, dónde cada fila actualizada por el`update`quedará registrada, en este caso solo no quedamos con el`numero`. En la segunda consulta de actualización usamos estos datos para saber que filas modificar. Te recomiendo que leas la documentación por que hay muchas particularidades con respecto a cuando y como puede usarse esta clausula.